# Compiling DPDK without all compiling/installing all Drivers

Tags: driver, dpdk

I need to use DPDK only in the KNI mode. For this i am not looking to compile all other drivers that dpdk compiles by default (igb_uio, vfio). Removing these would help me save compilation time.
Is there some way to achieve this ? Command line option would be better.

Thanks

Comment: are you looking at DPDK makefile or custom makefile or gcc commands to build DPDK?

Answer (score 0):

First do (use your config here, also for older versions it's linuxapp instead of linux):

```
make install T=x86_64-native-linux-gcc
cd build
```

And edit the .config file to your liking.
Drivers begin with `CONFIG_RTE_LIBRTE_PMD`. You can also disable libraries, but I'd be careful not to mess up any dependencies.